# C# Crystal Report PDF Exception

Tags: c#, memory, stream, crystal-reports-2010

I have  c# report PDF export project based on a dataTable I have manually created. I am using the following code to try and set the datasource and have tried many different variations but cannot get the information from my database to show up properly in my report exported as PDF. And saving as hard disk of my computer.

But when running the folllowing code, I can't see any PDF being exported. The exception is
below

CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.LogOnException: Database logon failedSystem.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Database logon failed.

I have set two data source , contract , contract members in main report
sub report for contract members

one contract can have many contract members.

It occurs at the last line

Any help is greatly appreciated. The below is my code

```
   string result;
            ContractReport report = new ContractReport();
            ContractDTO source = new ContractDTO();            
            report.Load(Server.MapPath("~/ContractReport.rpt"));
            source.Id = 1;
            source.Code = "ABC";
            source.Title = "LondonEast";          
            source.Member = new List<ContractMembersDTO>();
            source.Member.Add(new ContractMembersDTO() { Id = 1, ContractId = 1, StaffNameEng = "ABC", Position = "Project Manager" });
            source.Member.Add(new ContractMembersDTO() { Id = 2, ContractId = 1, StaffNameEng = "DEF", Position = "Project QS" });
            source.Member.Add(new ContractMembersDTO() { Id = 3, ContractId = 1, StaffNameEng = "GHI", Position = "Site Manager" });         
            report.SetDataSource(new[] { source });
            if (reportType.Equals("PDF"))
            {
                try
                {
                    MemoryStream oStream;
                    oStream = (MemoryStream)report.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
```

Comment: I have fought this sooooo many times. never found a distinct answer, but opening the report in CR designer (of a version that matches the runtime in use), and changing the connection information therein has always resolved it for me.

Comment: Yes, it has sub-reports and I have set two data source in the main report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got a single table in the report, your syntax *should* work...

```
report.SetDataSource(myCustomSource);
```

If your main report has multiple tables, try using this:

```
report.Database.Tables["DATASOURCE_TABLE_1"].SetDataSource(myCustomSource);
report.Database.Tables["DATASOURCE_TABLE_2"].SetDataSource(myOtherSource);
```

If you've got subreports, you'll need to set those individually too:

```
report.Subreports[0].SetDataSource(mySubreportDatasource);
```

Or

```
report.Subreports[0].Database.Tables[0].SetDataSource(mySubreportDatasource1);
report.Subreports[1].Database.Tables[0].SetDataSource(mySubreportDatasource2);
```

Comment: what if my database Tables are actually the POCO - classes ?

Comment: You mean assigning each table(POCO-classes with inputs) in the report indivisually? I have already added two tables as .nET Objects in the crystal reoprt setting